# Can AWS lambda to run ECR containers on specific instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

From AWS lambda, is it possible to specify the ECS instance types on which the ECR images run without creating clusters?

If a cluster is needed is it possible to have a 0 instance initial cluster (don't want an idle ec2 instance running).
Basically want to run a container on demand on a specific ec2 instance with lambda on demand, if possible.

Comment: What service do you want to use? EC2, ECS or Lambda? You mix and throw around different terms that apply to some of them but you cannot mix them as you wish.

Comment: lambda to trigger an ECS container running on a a specific type of instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run your container and your container does not actually need the more refined features that ECS-EC2 deployment allow, you should go for [ECS-Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/?nc=sn&loc=1&whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&fargate-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&fargate-blogs.sort-order=desc) which remove your concern of managing and paying for idling EC2 instances.

> Fargate removes the need to provision and manage servers, lets you specify and pay for resources per application, and improves security through application isolation by design.

AWS also announced another service that promises to further abstract the configuration needs that is [App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/)

And Lambda for sure, can trigger "the work that you want to run on your container", there should be numerous way that Lambda can send the signal for your container to start the work

Comment: yes agree fargate and app runner can do run apps. What  I am trying to see how to run a custom container on say a specific instance (like with gpu) on demand and want to avoid provisioning and scaling management.

Comment: The current theme for serverless type of products from AWS is that GPU workloads are not yet supported. So I am out of ideas : )